# Set up AsyncTask for loading data from SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

The onCreate() method below works fine in my Activity to create a CardView from SQLite data:

```
helper = new SQLiteDB(this);  
listItems = new ArrayList<>();
listItems = helper.getAllListItems();
```

When I try to set up an AsyncTask() method to replace the last line above and load the database data in the List, the CardView shows on the UI but does not populate with the SQLite data.  What am I missing here?

CardViewDetailsActivity

```
public class CardViewDetilsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<ListItem> listItems;
    private SQLiteDB helper;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dets);   

        final CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.dets);

        // Get the position of the clicked on R. list CardView from
        // the MainActivity's intent bundle.
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            // get the CardView item using the int position from the
            // MainActivity's onItemClick() and the putExtra in the intent.
            position = extras.getInt("position",0); 
        } 

        helper = new SQLiteDB(this);
        listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        listItems = helper.getAllListItems(); 
        // I tried to replace the last line above with:
        // "getDataFromSQLiteDB();" to launch the AsyncTask();

        ...
        cardType1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cardType1);
        ...  
        cardType1.setText(listItems.get(position).getType()); 
    } // End of onCreate();

    private void getDataFromSQLiteDB() {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                listItems.clear();
                listItems.addAll(helper.getAllListItems());
                // I also replaced the above two lines with 
                // helper.getAllListItems();

                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

SQLiteDB.java

```
public class SQLiteDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Get data from the database that the CardViewDetails Activity can use
    public List<ListItem> getAllListItems() {
    List<ListItem> modelList = new ArrayList<>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    ...
        return modeList;    
    }
}
```

Comment: No part of your question is displaying the data... Where is the adapter / listview?

Comment: By the way, using a Cursor + CursorAdapter would be recommended over getting an ArrayList + ArrayAdapter

Comment: I have a MainActivity that is a RecyclerView list of simple CardViews.  When I click on a CardView, the CardViewDetails Activity is launched via an Intent.  I just  want the same View as shown on the RecyclerView list for that CardView, but want to show it as a single CardView.

Comment: First off `new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()` returns nothing to `onPostExecute()`  I'd recommend returning your list data in `onPostExecute()` - the Result (`AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`) - then populate the cardView / RecyclerView or whatever there - your problem must be with you initialising the cardview with empty data. When using AsyncTask it doesn't block so all other initialisation code runs ..

Comment: @Mark Keen I will give it a try.

Comment: Okay, show a [mcve], then... The important piece of this question is the Adapter set to that RecyclerView, not the CardView

Comment: Also, you can still use Cursor w/ RecyclerView. https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59

Comment: The RecyclerView Adapter works fine to load all of the CardViews in the RecyclerView list.  I did not include the Adapter code because it is about 450 lines of Code and I thought it did not affect the CardViewDetails Activity.  Android newbie here, I don't understand how the MainActivity Adapter is important if I am finishing the MainActivity and then launching the CardViewDetails Activity.  Without the AsyncTask() the CardView view in CardViewDetails Activity shows properly without an Adapter, an ArrayAdapter or a CursorAdapter.  Please advise.

Comment: @Mark Keen No luck returning the list data in onPostExecute().  The CardView is returned but the TextViews are not populated with the data from the database.